# Nginx rewrite not working without trailing slash

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

This nginx rewrite rule only works with trailing slash, I need it working without slash.

I have tried few variation like without success.

```
rewrite ^/images/f([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)[d-].*$ /images/$2/ permanent;
```

This is example url which I need to redirect:

```
/images/f99/12345d678905-some-text_here-12345.jpg
```

This works:

```
/images/f99/12345d678905-some-text_here-12345.jpg/
```

I need "12345"

Comment: You probably have a separate location to process URIs that end with `.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

There was CORS rules for static extensions.
Thank you Richard Smith, I would have never figured on my own.